# Torah definition of אזרח, גר and תושב?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, sukkah

The Gemmorah in Succah (and Kiddushin) learns that the women are exempt from sitting in a Succah from the word האזרח.

The Torah uses this word a couple of times, many times together with the words גר or תושב.

Today, we use those words as follows:

- אזרח - a citizen of a state.
- תושב - a resident (with less civil rights)
- גר - a convert.

What meaning did the Torah have?